# cellForRowAtIndexPath called when table cell is clicked on to edit

Tags: tableview

When a table is created, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called to populate the cells.  Previously when a cell was clicked on to edit, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` wasn't called, and the cell could have text typed into it using:

```
#pragma mark Text Field Delegate Methods
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
self.textFieldBeingEdited = textField;
}
```

Now when I click on cells that are below the cell with row = 4, which is where the top of the keyboard is, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called with a row greater than the total number of rows causing a crash.  When I click on cells 0 to 4, I can edit the cells and cellForRowAtIndexPath  isn't called.  cellForRowAtIndexPath wasn't called previously for clicking on any of the cells.  I changed something that is causing this, but can't figure out what it is.

Does anyone know what can cause cellForRowAtIndexPath to be called when clicking on a cell to edit it?  It almost appears like it thinks a new table is being created.

Comment: Each cell contains a TextField.  If I disable the TextFields in the cells with row > 4, with
 
     textField.enabled = NO;

then cellForRowAtIndexPath does not get called when I tap on the cell.  Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.  I had specified one more row in the table than actually existed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this line:

```
[myTable reloadData];
```

Anywhere in the code, it will call CellForRowAtIndexPath again.